# How to extract all words that start with specific character from large file using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have very large file and looks like this:

```
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version "2"; exon_number "22"; gene_name "CDK11B"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "CDK11B-208"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "ENSE00001594002"; exon_version "1"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "5";
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version "2"; exon_number "22"; gene_name "CDK11B"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "CDK11B-208"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "ENSE00001594002"; exon_version "1"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "5";
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version "2"; exon_number "22"; gene_name "CDK11B"; gene_source "ensembl_havana"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_name "CDK11B-208"; transcript_source "ensembl"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "ENSP00000485937"; protein_version "1"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "5";
```

I would like to extract all the only the words that start with specific character "ENST"
I tried following  command :

```
 sed 's/.*\(ENST.*transcript_version\)/\1/p'
```

but it print outs all the lines. 
Would someone help me with this ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: To add to @sjam's comment: Your `sed` attempt suggest that you don't just want to extract the first word, but everything from the start of the line through `transcript_version`. Please clarify by directly updating your question.

Answer (score 6):

Use `grep` and `-o` option to print only the matched parts:

```
grep -Po '^ENST.*transcript_version' file
```

Comment: Nicely done. While `-P` will work fine with the _GNU_ `grep` found on Linux,  it is not needed here - just `-o` will do in this case (which will make the command work on BSD/macOS too).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. But why I mention `-P` option is that *perl-regex* will be more powerful. @mklement0.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed -E 's/^(ENST[[:digit:]]*.*transcript_version).*$/\1/' test11
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version
```

<sub>**Note**:The `-E` option enables extended regex, if it not supported use the `-r` option instead. Also, I feel the most elegant solution is [[ **this** ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666704/1620779).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be interested in sed solutions, or maybe you actually need an sed solution for some unusual reason.
(Otherwise I recommend a grep solution, e.g. one like provided by othere answers here. Might not be easy to check for transcript being there, but not print it, which I believe your description means, though your code is different. At least without greps `-P` option; which for example in my grep is not available. Or use perl, or awk.)

In order to:

- only print from lines which match, use `-n`
- only print "ENST00000629289"; transcript_version", use another `.*` at the end
- not print "; transcript_version" (not sure whether you actually want that), move the `\)`
- only print "ENST*" use a tighter regex `[[:alnum:]]*\).*` (with `\)` inside for above)

Code:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(ENST[[:alnum:]]*\).*transcript_version.*/\1/p'
```

Output:

```
ENST00000629289
ENST00000629289
ENST00000629289
```

Code 2 ( for including "transcript", in case you want that):

```
sed -n 's/.*\(ENST[[:alnum:]]*.*transcript_version\).*/\1/p'
```

Output 2:

```
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version
ENST00000629289"; transcript_version
```

My sed:
GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: It's also useful to explain that `grep` is just a subset of `sed`. (basically `sed` is `grep`'s big brother `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Calling `grep` a _subset_ of `sed` can be misleading, given that they're not _syntax-compatible_. By the same (loose) logic, `grep` is a "subset" of `awk`.